# Windows 7 - Allow remote desktop sessions while I'm logged in?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I have a development machine setup that a developer uses directly (monitor connected, etc).

We also serve up some development internal websites from this machine.

I need other people in the office to be able to remove desktop into the same machine, while the developer is using it, to run some of the software on that machine to configure the development settings.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with Remote Desktop, it will lock the user that's at the console out during the remote user's session.

You'll need to use VNC to actually share.  Something like tightvnc (http://www.tightvnc.com/) although last I checked there were issues on windows 7.

Alternatively, you might be able to use something like gotomeeting (or the like) to share control of your computer with another person - even though it's meant for meetings.

Comment: Update:  Looks like tightvnc will work now with windows 7.  http://www.tightvnc.com/faq.php